# What are good mounts (tripods, desk arm) capable of holding 2018 12.9inch iPad Pro?

Tags: monitors, tablet, monitor-stand

I have been looking for this like crazy but all items I find are not guaranteeing support for the 2018 iPad Pro size 12.9in.
I am looking for two things: a regular stand (I will use the iPad as a music reader so you know what I’m looking for) and a desk arm mount capable of holding this size and weight.
For the regular stand K&M produces some, but I’m not a fan of the quality of their screws so I’m open to suggestions.
For the arm mount I saw beautiful laptop and/or monitor mounts but, of course, they have VESA so: is there a good ordinary tablet arm mount capable of this or, alternatively, is there a kind of cover with a VESA adapter for the iPad so that I could use an ordinary monitor arm?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Dimensions per https://www.apple.com/ipad-pro/specs/ are 281 mm x 215 mm x 6mm and it masses 633 grams or less (depending on whether WiFi is present).

That is so much less than any 48 cm class display (smallest popular size), so a monitor arm will surely work, if [this PAD-TAM tablet arm offered by Zoro.com, their # G3890988](https://www.zoro.com/cta-digital-tablet-tabletop-arm-mount-gray-pad-tam/i/G3890988/feature-product) which specifically mentions the iPad 12.9", is not suitable.

The same vendor has a [free-standing stand "CTA Digital #PAD-AFS", Zoro # G2008268](https://www.zoro.com/cta-digital-height-adjustable-floor-stand-for-ipad-pad-afs/i/G2008268/#specifications) for your iPad.

A [search there for VESA](https://www.zoro.com/search?q=VESA) may provide the case you seek; if not, please provide a web link from a vendor or standard body which explains what a "VESA-case" is.

Comment: Could you please mention the vendor? The link returns “error 403”, Amazon CloudFront not accessible from my country. I’m aware of monitor arms, but I need a VESA-case for the iPad or it won’t attach to the arm.

Comment: I mean something that would hold the iPad and then allow it to be attached to a vesa-mount.

Comment: Dubious that CloudFront does not work in Italy after reading this: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/cloudfront-rome/  Perhaps your 403 error is in your ISP or DNS server, if Ctrl-Shift-Del does not clear it?

Comment: I’ve no idea... zoro.com or any of your links gives a 403 error. I’m now browsing the ctadigital.com website. Thanks